# <faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {https://svp.idt.net/WebServices/IDTSvpAPI}completeRequest</faultstring>

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soa, wsdl2java

I am getting 
Cannot find dispatch method for exception when I send the request. Could not find where the problem is.

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <idt:completeRequest>
         <idt:transactionId>1111</idt:transactionId>
         <idt:transactionTime></idt:transactionTime>
      </idt:completeRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>


   <S:Body>
      <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>ns2:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {https://svp.idt.net/WebServices/IDTSvpAPI}completeRequest</faultstring>
      </ns2:Fault>
   </S:Body>
```

WSDL file ---- Contract first approach

I am getting 
Cannot find dispatch method for exception when I send the request. Could not find where the problem is.

```
        <xsd:complexType name="transactResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="requestTransactionId" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="responseCode" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="processErrorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="transactResponse" type="tns:transactResponse"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="completeRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="transactionId" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="transactionTime" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="completeRequest" type="tns:completeRequest"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="completeResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="responseCode" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="processErrorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="completeResponse" type="tns:completeResponse"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="cancelRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="transactionId" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="statusCode" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="cancelRequest" type="tns:cancelRequest"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="cancelResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="responseCode" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="processErrorMessage" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="cancelResponse" type="tns:cancelResponse"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="transactRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:transactRequest" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="transactResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:transactResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="completeRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:completeRequest" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="completeResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:completeResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="cancelRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:cancelRequest" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="cancelResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:cancelResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="IDTSvpAPI">
    <wsdl:operation name="transact">
        <wsdl:input  message="tns:transactRequestMessage" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:transactResponseMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="complete">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:completeRequestMessage" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:completeResponseMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="cancel">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:cancelRequestMessage" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:cancelResponseMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="httpBinding_IDTSvpAPI" type="tns:IDTSvpAPI" >

    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="transact">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="https://svp.idt.net/WebServices/IDTSvpAPI/transact" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="complete">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output >
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="cancel">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="https://svp.idt.net/WebServices/IDTSvpAPI/cancel" />
        <wsdl:input name="cancelRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="cancelResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="IDTSvpService">
    <wsdl:port name="IDTSvpAPIPort" binding="tns:httpBinding_IDTSvpAPI">
        <soap:address location="/IdtSvpInterface/services" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```